# How to calculate a total by taking the radio button values using PHP and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, radio-button

I represent the questions from the database using php. Using an array I display them in a table. The radio buttons are grouped by giving a variable "i" in php as the name. Because of that I cannot get the values of those radio buttons to a javascript function to calculate the total.

This is how the table is represented:

[image: This is how the table is represented]

I want to calculate the total from the selected radio button values and send the value to another page. How do I do that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Below is my code.

```
<html>

<body>

 <?php
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'psych';

$connect = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);

    $res = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT questions FROM questions");

    $quests = mysqli_fetch_array($res);  

  ?>
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="../../Algorithms/score.php"> 

<table> 
  <th>
  <td width=100>Strongly agree </td>
  <td width=100>Agree </td>
  <td width=100>Neutral </td>
  <td width=100>Disagree </td>
  <td width=100>Strongly disagree </td>
  </th>
<?php 

$score=0;

    $i=1;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
     echo "<tr> <td width=500>".$i.". ".$row['questions']."</td>";
     echo '<td width=100> <input type="radio" name="'.$i.'"  value="1" > </td>';
     echo '<td width=100> <input type="radio" name="'.$i.'"  value="2" > </td>';
     echo '<td width=100> <input type="radio" name="'.$i.'"  value="3" > </td>';
     echo '<td width=100> <input type="radio" name="'.$i.'"  value="4" > </td>';
     echo '<td width=100> <input type="radio" name="'.$i.'"  value="5" > </td>';
       // if (score."$i") {echo "score$i";}
     echo "</tr>"; 
     // echo $scores[$i];
     //$scores[$i]=$_POST['score'.$i];
     $i++;

      }

    echo "</table>"; 
    echo "<br>"; 

  ?> 

  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
```

Comment: Where is your `form`? You have a HTML button of type `submit` but you don't have any form, it will not send the data to anything when you click on the button.

Comment: @NoahBoegli I'm sorry I must've deleted it when I pasted. Still it just loads the page. I don't understand how to get the values from the user inputs

Comment: You are naming your inputs dynamically. In your `../../Algorithms/score.php` you will have to create a loop to get the input values in the $_POST variable. If your input has the name set to `foo`, you will find the value in `$_POST['foo']`. 
You can use the same loop used to display the questions.

Comment: Can't I get all the values in the same php file and calculate the total and then pass that total value to `../../Algorithms/score.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , it will *better* to name your inputs with a meaningful names.

For example

```
echo '<td width=100> <input type="radio" name="score['.$i.']"  value="1" > </td>'
```

this will help you to distinguish between other fields - if you need to add another fields -

in server side , you are now have a array of inputs called `score` , you can sum/calculate the total with [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/array_sum) just like :

```
if (isset($_POST['score'])) {
    $total = array_sum($_POST['score']);
}
```

to save this value , you can use [`session`](https://www.php.net/session) with this

Comment: It gives an error saying "Undefined variable: total " when I try to pass the value. Below is what I tried. 

  ` if (isset($_POST['score'])) {
    $total = array_sum($_POST['score']);
  }

    echo "<a href=\"../../Algorithms/score.php?score=$total\">Click</a>"; `

Comment: where do you use the `$total` variable ?

Comment: put the `echo ...` inside the if condition

Comment: Then the click option goes. Doesn't display anything after the table

Comment: the click option should appear only if there are a `total` , it is useless if you didn't submitted the form

Comment: I'm a bit lost mate. Could you please show me the code to represent the total value after it's calculated and maybe how to send it to another page? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use same radio button but different values `<input type="radio" name="score" value="1" >`,`<input type="radio" name="score" value="2" >`.
2. In radio buttons pass the custom class like this `<input type="radio" class="cstm-radio" name="score" value="1" >`;
3. use on-click java-script or jquery event to get the value of clicked radio button and perform the ajax request, pass the url  of file or file name in which you have to perform back-end operation.

You can use this code to perform ajax request!

```
$('.cstm-radio').click(function () {
  var radio_val = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
    //url of your php file
    url: "post.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {score: radio_val},
    success: function (data) {
        // alert radio value here
        alert(data);
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Could you please help me with the 3rd option? I'm not very good at ajax or jquery

Comment: Ya sure give me some time.

Comment: Thanks alot mate. I want to calculate the total by the user input radio buttons and send the value to another page once a button is clicked.

Comment: How can I execute this? Should this be linked with a button?

Comment: No, just add this class "cstm-radio" in your radio buttons as i showed up.

Comment: It's not working mate. just shows the radio inputs but once im done clicking there's nothing else happening.

Comment: Is there something wrong here mate? `$('.cstm-radio').click(function ()`